# get_gameObject can only be called from the main thread

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use Unity3d for android platform,

I'm getting an error like below when I try to show a game object in `onRoomJoin` event.

```
get_gameObject can only be called from the main thread.
Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.
UnityEngine.Component:get_gameObject()
SFSConnect:OnRoomJoin(BaseEvent) (at Assets/SFSConnect.cs:861)
Sfs2X.Core.EventDispatcher:DispatchEvent(BaseEvent)
Sfs2X.SmartFox:DispatchEvent(BaseEvent)
Sfs2X.Controllers.SystemController:FnJoinRoom(IMessage)
Sfs2X.Controllers.SystemController:HandleMessage(IMessage)
Sfs2X.Core.SFSProtocolCodec:DispatchRequest(ISFSObject)
Sfs2X.Core.SFSProtocolCodec:OnPacketRead(ByteArray)
Sfs2X.Core.SFSIOHandler:HandlePacketData(ByteArray)
Sfs2X.Core.SFSIOHandler:OnDataRead(ByteArray)
Sfs2X.Bitswarm.BitSwarmClient:OnSocketData(Byte[])
Sfs2X.Core.ThreadManager:ProcessItem(Hashtable)
Sfs2X.Core.ThreadManager:InThread()
```

Here is my code as shown below:

```
public class SFSConnect : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject obj;

        void Start () {

        img = obj.GetComponent<Image> ();

        img.obj.SetActive (false);


        }

    void onRoomJoin(BaseEvent evt)
    {

        img.obj.SetActive (true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you calling onRoomJoin from? Is that being called from a plugin?

Comment: I use smartfoxapi, when I join smartfoxserver room it calls onRoomJoin event and I join room when scene is built

Comment: It is likely designed to make the callback in another Thread. See the dup for a script I made that you can use to run `img.obj.SetActive (true);` in the main thread.

Comment: @Programmer When I call `SetActive` from main thread like `Start()` , no errors are thrown. It happens only when I call it In `onRoomJoin(BaseEvent evt)` function, which makes me think that it's a different situation you've pointed as duplicate thread.

Comment: *"When I call SetActive from main thread like Start() , no errors are thrown"* That's because `Start` is being called in the main Thread. Almost all Unity callback functions are being called in the main thread except for the audio callback function and few others. *"It happens only when I call it In onRoomJoin(BaseEvent evt) function"*...Again, that's because `onRoomJoin` is being called from another Thread that's not a main Thread. You can't use most Unity's API in another Thread. Using the function in my dup to make that call should in the `onRoomJoin` func should fix it.

Comment: @Programmer I use UnityThread script but `void Update` function doesn't triggered, what should I do?

Comment: You are suppose to attach `UnityThread` script to an empty GameObject. That's it. How to use it on the other answer. Please don't comment multiple places if you want a reply. Just comment on one place.

Comment: So sorry, I don't understand what you said

Comment: 1.Attach the `UnityThread` script to an empty GameObject. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I fixed this, thanks, so can you help me another issue? how to useUnityThread.executeInUpdate method with parameter like this `void example(string a, int b)`

Comment: How about you read the answer from the duplicate. It explains how to use that under where it says **"USAGE"**.  


`UnityThread.executeInUpdate(() =>
{
    example("Hellow", 4);
});`....

Also, you don't have to attach the `UnityThread` script to an empty GameObject like I mentioned above. Just call `UnityThread.initUnityThread();` from the your scripts's `Awake` function and it will attach it for you. Just read that answer carefully since it explains these pretty much.

Comment: Thanks in advance,  I already use that you mentioned, just calling awake function this `UnityThread.initUnityThread();`